# Pandas Dataframe (inner) Join on the same Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I'm working on how to cluster a patstat (reference database) database.

With my own agorithm I came up with a dataframe which shows me the author, beginpage, endpage, volume and publication_year of a reference.

running:

```
dfhead = df.head(10)
```

shows me

[image]

Now I want the following:
Show inner join with the SAME dataframe such that for example author, beginpage and endpage are the same. (at least 3 similarities between the rows)

I tried:

```
c = ['author', 'beginpage','endpage', 'volume','publication year']
df_merge = dfhead.merge(dfhead, how = 'inner',on = [c[0],c[1],c[2]])
```

where

The answer will then be given such that there only exists an inner join with exactly the same row, but I don't want those to include.
In the example above the `df_merge` should not take any values since there are no 3 similar columns.

What if there would be some how to same row, I will show an example:

```
x = pd.Dataframe({'author':['lee','lee'], 'beginpage':[455,456],'endpage':[477,477],'volume':[300,300]})
```

Note that the two rows have (at least) 3 similar columns and therefore the merge/join should be visible.
BUT note that in don't want to include to join of exactly the same row!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do an inner join and apply filtering to exclude the same row, but maybe it would be more straightforward to use groupby instead?

```py
df.groupby(by=['author', 'beginpage','endpage'])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Applying aggregations/calculations/ect to groups:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html

Comment: I was trying to exclude the same row, but the problem is that I don't know how to program that.

Comment: There is a problem with using groupby pandas, since the goal of my exercise is that I want to show at least 3 of the same similarities in a row and I have 5 columns to check on. See the C array in the above mentioned code. Therefore for just 2 rows you have to check on 10 (5ncr3) different combinations.